# Не работает canvas в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

Пытался отрисовать картинку и ничего. Попробовал линию. Снова ничего. Подскажите, что можно сделать, чтобы всё стало ок. В консоли ошибок нет.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas3" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
    let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas3');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let cosmos = new Image();
    cosmos.src = 'https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/51/219186-frederika.jpg';
    ctx.drawImage(cosmos, 0, 0, 640, 480);
```

Comment: Вы рисуете картинку еще до того, как она загрузилась

Comment: Точно. Спасибо, помогло